# Leetcode longest substring without repeating characters

Tags: python, c++, programming-challenge

[Link here](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/)
I'm currently learning c++ coming from a python background, so I'll include a solution in python and in c++ for the following problem statement and based on very helpful answers obtained on my previous [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/251403/leetcode-two-sum) I made some improvements in the c++ implementation:

> Given a string s, find the length of the longest substring without repeating characters.

**Example 1:**

Input: s = "abcabcbb"
Output: 3

**Example 2:**

Input: s = "bbbbb"
Output: 1

I would like to improve speed for both python and c++ implementations, and I need to improve memory consumption in the c++ implementation since I got a very high figure (600+ MB) as well as the reasons for this high consumption (if the figure is accurate), and I would like general suggestions too.

`longest_substring.py`

```
def get_longest(s: str):
    possibilities = (s[i:] for i in range(len(s)))
    maximum = 0
    for possibility in possibilities:
        end_idx = maximum
        while end_idx <= len(possibility):
            current_chunk = possibility[0:end_idx]
            end_idx += 1
            if not (current_size := len(current_chunk)) == len(set(current_chunk)):
                break
            maximum = max(current_size, maximum)
    return maximum


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f'Longest substring:\n{get_longest("abcabcbb")}')
```

Leetcode stats:

> Runtime: 260 ms, faster than 19.36% of Python3 online submissions for Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters.

> Memory Usage: 14.4 MB, less than 100.00% of Python3 online submissions for Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters.

`longest_substring.h`

```
#ifndef LEETCODE_LONGEST_SUBSTRING_H
#define LEETCODE_LONGEST_SUBSTRING_H

#include <string>

int longest_sub(const std::string &s);
bool check_unique(const std::string &s);

#endif //LEETCODE_LONGEST_SUBSTRING_H
```

`longest_substring.cpp`

```
#include "longest_substring.h"
#include <iostream>
using std::endl;
using std::cout;
using std::string;


bool check_unique(const string &s) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size() - 1; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = i + 1; j < s.size(); ++j) {
            if (s[i] == s[j])
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


int longest_sub(const string &s) {
    int maximum = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
        const string possibility = s.substr(i);
        auto end_idx = maximum;
        while (end_idx < possibility.size()) {
            const string current_chunk = possibility.substr(0, ++end_idx);
            if (!check_unique(current_chunk))
                break;
            auto current_size = current_chunk.size();
            if (current_size > maximum)
                maximum = current_size;
        }
    }
    return maximum;
}


int main() {
    cout << "Longest substring: " << endl;
    cout << longest_sub("abcabcbb");
}
```

Leetcode stats:

> Runtime: 100 ms, faster than 14.88% of C++ online submissions for Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters.

> Memory Usage: 604.2 MB, less than 5.02% of C++ online submissions for Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Complexity

Your solution has [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) \$\mathcal{O}(N^4)\$, which is very bad. There is a \$\mathcal{O}(N)\$ solution for this problem. Consider for example the string:

```
abcdecfghij
```

Instead of taking substrings and checking if the substring has duplicates, instead keep track of the last position seen for any possible character. This is basically an array of 256 ints, which you should initialize to -1 to indicate that you've never seen the character before. Then, iterate over the string character by character, and check if the character you look at has already been seen. If not, update its position in the array. So after processing `abcde`, you will have `a = 0, b = 1, c = 2, d = 3, e = 4` and the rest is still `-1`. Then when you encounter `c` again, you know you have a duplicate. But instead of starting over from the second character of the string, you should start instead from the character right after the first `c`, so at position 3. And you know you already have a valid substring up to and including the second `c`. So then you can continue from there. You continue until you find a character with a recorded position that is equal to or more than the starting position of the current substring. Here is a possible implementation in C++:

```
#include <array>
#include <utility>

int longest_sub(const std::string &s) {
    std::array<int, 256> last_positions;
    last_positions.fill(-1);

    int min_position = 0;
    int maximum_length = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
        int &last_position = last_positions[static_cast<unsigned char>(s[i])];

        if (last_position >= min_position) {
            // We encountered a duplicate
            min_position = last_position + 1;
        }

        maximum_length = std::max(maximum_length, int(i + 1 - min_position));
        last_position = i;
    }

    return maximum_length;
}
```

Comment: I don't know how they calculate memory usage. I don't see your code having any memory leaks, so it shouldn't use that much.

Comment: I think you mean `a = 0, b = 1, c = 2, d = 3, e = 4`

Comment: Btw, you really should consider [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) for the argument.

Comment: @Deduplicator The API is determined by LeetCode in this case, but otherwise you would be right.

Comment: Those top-coder, elite-coder, coding-challenge and assorted sites really get on my nerves with all their ante-diluvian super-pessimized code which nobody in their right mind ever thought barely adequate. And it just keeps coming. Still, as you restricted yourself to the big picture, I took the litte details.

Comment: @Deduplicator Thanks, you have some excellent additions! I'm already glad that no `<bits/stdc++.h>` were `#include`d in OP's post.

Comment: @Deduplicator I don't like these coding challenges because they are not realistic and most of the questions are testing you for things that are not very useful in real life, I learned that one day when I was starting to learn python, I kept solving project Euler problems one by one, after a while specially when I started to write some useful code, I realized that you get the actual useful experience from practicing real world problems. However they are good when you're new to some language and you don't want to go hardcore on day1

Comment: @G.Sliepen What does this expression do? `last_positions[static_cast<unsigned char>(s[i])]`

Comment: @bullseye: it gets the element in the array `last_positions[]` at the index given by the character `s[i]`. You have to cast `s[i]` to an `unsigned char`, because a `char` might be signed.

Comment: Minor performance improvement: halve the memory usage of the `last_positions` array by using `uin16_t` elements instead of `int` (the linked problem assures that "`0 <= s.length <= 5 * 10^4`"). You'll then need an unsigned alternative for the -1 default, so just have the array hold 1-indexed positions instead of 0-indexed positions: that way you can just zero-initialize the array (`= {};`) instead of calling `.fill()` at all.

Comment: @Will I'm not sure it will make much of a difference; even with `int`s the array only takes up 1 kilobyte, which should have no trouble fitting into the L1 cache of the CPU. Maybe you win some by using a zero-filled array, but lose some by having to add 1 to the indices. A micro-optimization like this should be benchmarked to see if it really helps.

Comment: @G.Sliepen "it gets the element in the array `last_positions[]` at the index given by the character `s[i]`" I don't get the meaning of index given by a character, ex: `s[0]` for `s` being `"abc"` is `'a'` what I don't understand is that `last_positions[]` is indexed using normal indices (0, 1, 2 ...) as well as characters ('a') in that case, does this imply the ascii order? (97 for `'a'` respectively) or there is something I don't understand?

Comment: @bullseye: each character has a numerical value. On almost all systems, they indeed follow the ASCII order, at least for values between 0 and 127.

Answer (score 6):

[G. Sliepen](/u/129343) already took care of the big picture issues, where you get the most bang for the buck.

Still, there are a few issues with the code aside from using a sub-optimal algorithm:

1. You should consider [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) for the string-argument, and for getting a temporary slice of a long-lived string.
   Dynamic allocation is pretty expensive, and best avoided, both on calling a function if the input might not be in the desired format, and in the function itself.
   See "*[What is `string_view`?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/20803826/what-is-string-view)*" and "*[How exactly is `std::string_view` faster than `const std::string&`?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/40127965/how-exactly-is-stdstring-view-faster-than-const-stdstring)*" for more details.
2. Now that the functions no longer allocate memory, or contain any other potential exception-thrower, mark them `noexcept` so everyone knows (and the compiler enforces) that it won't throw. It won't do much of anything here, but is good documentation, informs the compiler if it only knows the declaration, and can be important later with using templated code consuming it for best performance and highest exception-safety guarantees.
3. Also, mark them `constexpr` while you are at it, to allow use in constant expression, and encourage evaluation at compile-time. That is also a best-practice thing not actually changing much of anything for your example program itself.
4. You use `std::cout` twice (whyever you don't push all the output into it in a single expression escapes me there, but that can be argued either way), and `std::endl` once. Writing (and keeping in mind) those two using-declarations costs more than prefixing the uses with `std::`. Even if you really dislike writing `std::`, you don't write it less often.
5. Don't force flushing a stream unless you really mean it, as it flushes performance down the drain. `std::endl` outputs a newline and then flushes, `stream << std::endl` being exactly equivalent to `stream << '\n' << std::flush`. Thus if you really have to, better be explicit and use `std::flush`.
   See "*[What is the C++ iostream `endl` fiasco?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5492380/what-is-the-c-iostream-endl-fiasco)*" for more detail.